# Display batch filename on top of the execution window

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have got 2 batch files, say A.bat and B.bat, which I need to keep open at the same time on my desktop.
When I open the batch file window, I see C:\Windows32\cmd.exe written on top of each window.
This really confuses me as to which window corresponds to which batch file.

Thus, is there a way I can display A on the window corresponding to A.bat and same for B?

I didn't get any cues on the web which brought me here.

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You could use the `title` command for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the first line of each .bat file read:

```bat
@Title %~nx0
```